# Play audio file on website

Tags: php

I'm just wondering how, and which audio player I should use to allow my visitors to play audio files on my PHP-based website.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<?php
$path = "PATH OF YOUR AUDIO FILE";
$image = "PATH OF YOUR IMAGEFILE";;?>

<div class="demomain">
<br>
<div style="margin: 0 0 0 30px;" id="mediaspace" name="mediaspace"><embed height="395"  width="500" flashvars="javascriptid=JW&amp;autostart=false&amp;width=500&amp;height=395&amp;image=<?php echo $image; ?>&amp;file=<?php echo $path; ?>" allowfullscreen="true" wmode="transparent" allowscriptaccess="always" quality="high" name="JW" id="JW" style="undefined" src="http://player.longtailvideo.com/player4.6.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">       </div>
<?php
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
var s1 = new SWFObject("","JW","500","395","9");
s1.addParam("allowscriptaccess", "always");
s1.addParam("wmode","transparent");
s1.addParam("allowfullscreen","true");
s1.addVariable("javascriptid", "JW");
s1.addVariable("autostart","false");
s1.addVariable("image","' . $image . '"));
s1.addVariable("width","500");
s1.addVariable("height","395");';
echo 's1.addVariable("file","' . $path . '");'; 
echo 's1.write("mediaspace");';
echo '</script>';
?>
</div>
```

Comment: If flash (SWF) is installed on the computer/availabe for the browser

Answer (score 2):

HTML 5 has an audio player tag,see this: 
http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_audio_src.asp
it is supported on major browsers, but it depends on the format of the audio file

you can see this: http://jplayer.org/ a jquery one,

Answer (score 1):

The open source jPlayer works well and is very customisable - uses HTML/CSS for the interface.  Will use HTML5 if it can, and fallback to Flash if not.  Requires jQuery.

Website: http://jplayer.org/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<object height="81" width="100%">
  <param name="movie" value="http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F32222617&amp;show_comments=true&amp;auto_play=true">
  </param>
  <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
  <embed allowscriptaccess="always" height="81" src="http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F32222617&amp;show_comments=true&amp;auto_play=true&amp;repeat=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%" loop="yes" autoresume="1" repeat="1">
  </embed>
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try Flash Player. I think it will suite your requirement. Of course you should have the flash player installed, but practically almost all internet users have the flash player installed in their machines.

Answer (score 0):

use this `<audio controls><source src="<?php echo $pathtofile ?>" type="audio/mpeg">Error loading</audio>` It works for me.