# Php header for .wav file download but cannot play in embed

Tags: php, wav

I have to build the header for a .wav file for it to play in the  element.

```
$filename =  basename($_GET['file']);

$pos = strrpos($file, '.');

$extension = ($pos !== false) ? substr($file, $pos) : '';

$mime_type = "";
switch ($extension) {
    case '.mp3':
        $mime_type = "audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3";
        break;
    case '.ulaw':
        $mime_type = "audio/basic";
        break;
    case '.gsm':
        $mime_type = "audio/x-gsm";
        break;
    case '.wav':
        $mime_type = "audio/x-wav, audio/wav";
        break;
}

if(file_exists($filename)){
    $handle = fopen($filename, "rb");

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
    header('Content-Type: '.$mime_type);
    header('Content-length: ' . filesize($filename));
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $filename.'"');

    while (!feof($handle)) {
        echo fread($handle, 4096);
        flush();
    }
    fclose($handle);
}else{
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}
```

This is called by `www.example.com/listen?file=Test.en.wav`

For now, when I go on that page, the file downloads and works (Half of what I want), but when I try :

```
<embed src="www.example.com/listen?file=Test.en.wav">
```

The player appears, but the file doesn't/can't play.

Edit : I would like to know if it is possible to make it play and how?

Comment: You have posted whole player code above? Echo only prints out the conents of a file, how is it supposed to PLAY the .wav?

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't very specific. Want I want to know is how to play the file, if it is possible. Thank you!

Comment: Hello, I don't know if this intentional but `echo fread($handle, 4096);` will only display the first 4 mB of a file ...

Comment: I'm not sure if it's even possible in PHP. You can try alternative solutions, but most of them involve Flash technology. http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/ Have you used search function on SO? try this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185280/play-audio-file-on-website

Comment: It wasn't, but my file are all smaller than 4 mB, so it would't have been a problem. Thank you!

Comment: what browser? what plugins?

Comment: I strongly suspect that it has to do with `header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $filename.'"');` because it forces the download of the file. Try changing it to `header('Content-Disposition: inline;filename="' . $filename.'"');`

Comment: @Ejay Thank you, halfway there, now I think I just have plugin problem since .mp3 work with firefox and .wav work with Chrome but not the other way arround.

Comment: Have you tryed a basic html5 audio player? (for testing purposes)  http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp

Comment: for Firefox behaviour, see this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Comment: You probably want `<embed src="http://www.example.com`, not `<embed src="www.example.com`, for starters. Without the scheme, it'll be interpreted as a relative link, which'll mean you're actually including `http://www.example.com/www.example.com/listen?file=Test.en.wav`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a switch/case block, why not use PHP's function `mime_content_type()`?

Example:

```
<?php
$file="/path/to/file.wav";
$mime_type=mime_content_type($file);
echo $mime_type;
?>
```

Output: `audio/x-wav`

Comment: As a general rule, you should not depend on the file extension to determine a document's content type. Don't be like Microsoft!

Answer (score 0):

Try `audio/vnd.wave`.

Per [RFC 2361](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2361)

Also try only specifying a single MIME type per request instead of a comma separated list.

```
case '.mp3':
    $mime_type = "audio/mpeg";
```

You'll probably also need to install something like [Quicktime](http://www.apple.com/quicktime/) in order to play these directly in your browser. Some browsers do attempt content [MIME] sniffing to fix faulty MIME types.

- [Internet Explorer Content Sniffing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147.aspx)
- [Firefox Content Sniffing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/How_Mozilla_determines_MIME_Types)
- [Chrome](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/net/base/mime_sniffer.cc?revision=HEAD&view=markup)

Comment: If I use only 1 mime for mpeg, they stop playing in firefox, .wav still dont want to play on firefox, but they work in chrome. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Remove other headers and just set "Content-Type" header

```
header('Content-Type: '.$mime_type);
```